# connect to ppp interface

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, ppp

I have a remote device running Linux with public ip address.
Snippet from remote device `ifconfig -a`:

```
ppp0 Link encap: Point-to-Point Protocol
     inet addr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx P-t-P: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mask: 255.255.255.255
     etc...
```

I want to get access to the device (ssh, or something).
Ho can i do it?

Comment: ssh username@ipaddress. If the ssh service is running and the port is not blocked, if the ssh is configured to allow passwords to be accepted, if you know the password, you'll be in. As you can see, there is a lot of ifs.

Comment: I do know all credentials. I have tried to ssh to the device (i get connection timed out). 
Actually, first thing i have tried is to ping the device, i got connection timed out, but i do not know if this is because PPP is used on that interface or something else.

Comment: Should i get a ping response if i try to ping device on PPP interface?

Comment: Depends if the devices inbuilt firewall is configured to reject ping requests or not.

Comment: Suppose there are no firewall rules that can block the traffic, in other words all is open. If i ping the device on public PPP interface, should i get a response?
Same thing with ssh, if ssh server is running on port default port (22), there are no firewall rules should i be able to access device?

Comment: So long as there is not NAT issues then yes.